# Problemas ao acessar membros de structs

Tags: c, array, funções, struct

Tenho que fazer algumas funções com essas structs, mas uma vez que Agenda tem um vetor de structs Contato e em cada contato tem outra struct Data, como faço para acessar os campos? Tenho que trabalhar cada struct de forma separada? Grato desde já, segue o código.

```
typedef struct Data{
    int dia,mes,ano;
}t_data;

typedef struct Contato{
    char nome[40];
    char fone[12];
    int idade;
    t_data dataNascimento;
}t_contato;

typedef struct Agenda{
    t_contato contatos[200];
}t_agenda;
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua dúvida bem. No modo que está fazendo, o certo acredito que seria ter uma variável do tipo `t_contato` sendo de nome `Agenda`. Algo como: `t_contato Agenda[200]`. Você acessaria: `Agenda[indice].dataNascimento.Dia`, por exemplo.

Comment: Na verdade havia apenas duas estruturas Contato e Agenda, porém na struct Contato havia esse membro que entendi como sendo outra struct:  

dataNascimento: Data(Dia, mês e ano int). 

Estava tentando responder conforme o enunciado, mas acho que vou seguir a maneira que você sugeriu! Obg o/

Comment: Sim, ela realmente é outra estrutura. E é normal haver uma struct dentro de outra. Mas vejo o modo que falei mais "correto" pois sendo assim, todas as suas agendas teriam um limite de 200 contatos, não poderia ser mais ou menos. No modo que disse, você pode ter uma agenda com N contatos. Por exemplo> `t_contato AgendaDois[10]`. A não ser que a estrutura de contatos dentro de `Agenda` fosse dinâmico. Acredito que alguém com mais conhecimento conceitual pode responder melhor logo logo.

Comment: Cara você começou a fazer suas funções ?                             para manipular a STRUCT, se elas vão ser passagem por valor ou referencia, se for por valor tem um tipo de acesso a variável é por referencia tem outro tipo, manja criar função com VOID                            exemplo: http://linguagemc.com.br/funcao-com-passagem-por-referencia/

Comment: Sim! Vi alguns exemplos e tinha noção de como fazer, mas tava travando nessa parte de acessar os structs da forma como foram apresentados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supondo que você declarou uma `t_agenda` como o escrito abaixo, para acessar um elemento do vetor `contatos`, você deve fazer da seguinte forma:

```
//declaração da variavel
t_agenda agenda;
//acessa o dia do t_data, onde `indice` deve ser substituido pelo valor do indice
agenda.contatos[indice].dataNascimento.dia;
```